# How to get values from RDD dynamically with Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Below is sample record for a book in our system on campus.  Each book record is a text file.  I have loaded up records with:

```
books = sc.wholeTextFiles (file:///data/dir/*/*/*/”)
```

This would give me a RDD.  One record in the RDD looks like this:

```
[[‘Call No: 56CB',
  'Title:  Global Warming',
  'Type: Serial,
  'Database:  AWS898,',
 ‘Microfilm:  Y,',
  'Access:  Public ,',
]]
```

I am trying to extract the values in the 4 to N tuple positions of the RDD.  0 through 4 tuples are always there.  But the RDD may be missing the 5th and beyond tuples, like this:

```
[[‘Call No: 56CB',
  'Title:  Science 101',
  'Type: Serial,’
  'Database:  AWS898,',
   ‘Microfilm:  Y,',
]]
```

So, the code has to be flexible to handle the variable length of the RDD.  I have the following code that gets me the 4 and 5 tuples, but this is not flexible when the RDD has 4 through 15 tuples:

```
Summary1 = books.map(lambda x: (x[4]))
Summary2 = books.map(lambda x: (x[5]))
```

I can get the length of the RDD with:

```
LenRDD = books.map(lambda x: len(x)).collect()
```

Can you help me write the python code that gets me dynamically the 4th to LenRDD tuples?

Here is an example of one of the files:

```
Call No: 56CB
Title:  Global Warming
Type: Serial
Database:  AWS894
Microfilm:  Y
Access:  Public
Location: Oxford
Size:  987 MB
Key:  677867IPOIO
```

Comment: please share what you've tried so far and specify your specific problem.

Comment: I have tried a for loop, but is there some other solution?  The problem is that I am trying to extract values out of the RDD and produce a report.  The problem is that the RDD may not have all of the tuples beyond the 4th one.  But I need to get those ones.  Does this help?

Comment: can share some sample lines from the text tiles. format should be the same. and update that in the question.

Comment: Did you try filter function?
books.filter(lambda x: x[4:]).map(lambda x: x[4:])

Comment: I guess if you want to get tuple from 4 to end then you don&#39;t need filter either. Just use map.
Books.map(lambda x: x[4:])

Comment: What I am not understanding is why did you use wholeTextFiles for. wholeTextFiles would read all the text in a file as a single text. so `Summary1 = books.map(lambda x: (x[4]))` is not going to work as each x will have only x[0] and x[1]. where x[0] represents file name and x[1] represents the whole text of that file. are you getting my point?

Comment: According to what I understand from your question, you are trying to filter out the first 4 lines of each text files and retain the rest of the lines of each file in rdds. Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: Ramesh, you are right.  I just grab the contents of the file.  I don't need the file name.

Comment: Sunnysinh Solanki, thanks for code, books.filter(lambda x: x[4:]).map(lambda x: x[4:]) .  That worked.  I did not know I could put a : next to the integer for the tuple.  I have tested it with various RDD sizes and it worked fine.

Comment: I can't assign points.  Not sure what happend.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand from your question, **you are trying to filter out the first 4 lines of each text files and retain the rest of the lines of each file in rdds**. If my understanding is correct then you should read the files as you are doing

```
books = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///data/dir/*/*/*/")
```

Then you write a *function* to delete the first four records from an array

```
def delete(x):
    if(len(x)>4):
        for index in range(0,4):
            del x[0]
    return x
```

and then use the above *function* to delete the first four lines from each text files and get the rest of the lines as rdd

```
summary1 = books.map(lambda x: delete(x[1].split("\n"))).map(lambda x: "\n".join(x))
```

You should get what you are looking for

Comment: didn't the answer helped you? if it did you should consider accepting it :)