# How to call a defined function with map()?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to call a defined function with the map(). I understand that that the map function appl the same procedure to every item in an iterable data structure. But the defined is not being called.

I have a define function, like this:

```
def process (records):
    fields = records.map(lambda x: x.split('ID:')[0].split('\n'))
    return fields;
```

Here is the map() and the defined function being called:

```
files = sc.wholeTextFiles ('file:///data/*/*')
records = files.map(lambda x: process(x))
```

There are 4,560 files loaded up by wholeTextFiles, so there is data there. Perhaps, I am missing something basic. Can you help?

Comment: Your code doesn't have the unmatched single quotes in line 2 right? If it did, you would be having a whole different set of issues, so I assume you just messed up copying.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: I don't know Python, but if `process_countries()` is not being called, my first guess would be that `countries` doesn't have anything in it, so when you call `countries.map()`, nothing happens. Try checking whether `countries` is empty; if it is, it might be because `files` is empty. And I suppose that might be because your regex isn't finding anything? If you're still stuck after that, come back and indicate your results of checking `files` and `countries`. That might be a good clue for the people here who know Python.

Comment: Also, make totally sure whether `process_countries()` is being called or not. Like set a breakpoint inside it, or print something out at the beginning of it.

Comment: As a note, if you load the data with `sc.textFile` instead of `sc.wholeTextFiles`, you can skip the map set. `textFile` can handle globs.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I misread what you're doing.

Comment: python groups statements with spaces in the front. And I don't see any statement for process_countries function as the next line starts at the same position of the function definition. Is that a formatting mistake while copying? And looking at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959246/how-to-get-values-from-rdd-dynamically-with-python) it seems that you are splitting the texts in a wrong way.

Comment: can you include input data stating what should be considered cities and what should be considered population?

Comment: I will rewrite my question to simplify things.

Comment: RDDs are lazy... You've not called an action, therefore nothing will be called by Spark... So where are you trying to show output? What are you getting?

Comment: Right, its not being called, so nothing is return.  Records is empty. So, how would I do this in python using the map()?